# Spark 1.6 DataFrame optimize join partitioning

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a question about Spark DataFrame partitioning, I'm currently using Spark 1.6 for project requirements.This is my code excerpt:

```scala
sqlContext.getConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions") // 6

val df = sc.parallelize(List(("A",1),("A",4),("A",2),("B",5),("C",2),("D",2),("E",2),("B",7),("C",9),("D",1))).toDF("id_1","val_1")
df.rdd.getNumPartitions // 4

val df2 = sc.parallelize(List(("B",1),("E",4),("H",2),("J",5),("C",2),("D",2),("F",2))).toDF("id_2","val_2")
df2.rdd.getNumPartitions // 4

val df3 = df.join(df2,$"id_1" === $"id_2")
df3.rdd.getNumPartitions // 6

val df4 = df3.repartition(3,$"id_1")
df4.rdd.getNumPartitions // 3

df4.explain(true)
```

The following is the explain plan has been created:

```scala
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'RepartitionByExpression ['id_1], Some(3)
+- Join Inner, Some((id_1#42 = id_2#46))
   :- Project [_1#40 AS id_1#42,_2#41 AS val_1#43]
   :  +- LogicalRDD [_1#40,_2#41], MapPartitionsRDD[169] at rddToDataFrameHolder at <console>:26
   +- Project [_1#44 AS id_2#46,_2#45 AS val_2#47]
      +- LogicalRDD [_1#44,_2#45], MapPartitionsRDD[173] at rddToDataFrameHolder at <console>:26

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id_1: string, val_1: int, id_2: string, val_2: int
RepartitionByExpression [id_1#42], Some(3)
+- Join Inner, Some((id_1#42 = id_2#46))
   :- Project [_1#40 AS id_1#42,_2#41 AS val_1#43]
   :  +- LogicalRDD [_1#40,_2#41], MapPartitionsRDD[169] at rddToDataFrameHolder at <console>:26
   +- Project [_1#44 AS id_2#46,_2#45 AS val_2#47]
      +- LogicalRDD [_1#44,_2#45], MapPartitionsRDD[173] at rddToDataFrameHolder at <console>:26

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
RepartitionByExpression [id_1#42], Some(3)
+- Join Inner, Some((id_1#42 = id_2#46))
   :- Project [_1#40 AS id_1#42,_2#41 AS val_1#43]
   :  +- LogicalRDD [_1#40,_2#41], MapPartitionsRDD[169] at rddToDataFrameHolder at <console>:26
   +- Project [_1#44 AS id_2#46,_2#45 AS val_2#47]
      +- LogicalRDD [_1#44,_2#45], MapPartitionsRDD[173] at rddToDataFrameHolder at <console>:26

== Physical Plan ==
TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id_1#42,3), None
+- SortMergeJoin [id_1#42], [id_2#46]
   :- Sort [id_1#42 ASC], false, 0
   :  +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id_1#42,6), None
   :     +- Project [_1#40 AS id_1#42,_2#41 AS val_1#43]
   :        +- Scan ExistingRDD[_1#40,_2#41] 
   +- Sort [id_2#46 ASC], false, 0
      +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id_2#46,6), None
         +- Project [_1#44 AS id_2#46,_2#45 AS val_2#47]
            +- Scan ExistingRDD[_1#44,_2#45]
```

As far I know, `DataFrame` represent an abstraction interface over `RDD`, so partitioning should be delegated to the **Catalyst** optimizer.

Infact compared to `RDD` where many transformations accept a number of partitions parameter, in order to optimize co-partitioning and co-locating whenever possible, with `DataFrame` the only chance to alter partitioning, is invoking the method repartition, otherwise the number of partitions for join and aggregations is inferred using the configuration param `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`.

From what I can see and understand from the explain plan above it seems there is an **useless repartition(so shuffle indeed)** to 6 (the default value) after then repartitioning again to the final value imposed by the method repartition.

I believe the Optimizer could change the number of partitions of the join to the final value of 3.

Could someone help me to clarify that point? Maybe I missing something.

Comment: With small volumes if is harder to follow. With larger volumes and setting shuffles partitions you tend to get that number of partitions actually used. V 2.3.1 at least

Comment: The partitioning scheme followed during join is HashPartitioning as you can see in the explain plan. The number of partitions after the join will be equal to `spark.sql.shufle.partitions` but the data distribution could be different. For instance, in your example you have 4 distinct IDs so out of the 6 partitions that `df3` has, 2 will be empty and will not result in any job/task/stage.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spark sql, your shuffle partitions is always equal to spark.sql.shufle.partitions.But if you enable this spark.sql.adaptive.enabled it will add EchangeCoordinator.Right now, the work of this coordinator is to determine the number of post-shuffle partitions for a stage that needs to fetch shuffle data from one or multiple stages.